# Как реализовать сервер на сокетах с использованием системного вызова select()?

Tags: linux, c, сокет

Как реализовать сервер на сокетах на C с использованием системного вызова select().
Необходимо написать echo сервер, к которому могли бы подключаться несколько клиентов, без использования fork() и без создания потоков, то есть используя select().

Здесь же нашёл пример кода подходящего, понятно, что нужно делать, для того, чтобы сервер отправлял те же сообщения клиенту, который ему отправил клиент, но непонятно, как и где использовать select().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept");
     bzero(buffer,256);
     n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
     printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
     n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше использовать poll().
Вот мой пример:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <poll.h>

#define MAX_CLIENTS 8
#define SERVER_PORT 10000

int main()
{
    int listen_sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (listen_sock_fd < 0)
    {
        printf("server: Cannot create TCP socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    int opt = 1;
    if (0 != setsockopt(listen_sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void*) &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        printf("server: Error: could not allow reuse address on socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(listen_sock_fd);
        return 0;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr = {0};
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    if (-1 == bind(listen_sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)))
    {
        printf("server: Error on call 'bind': %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    if (-1 == listen(listen_sock_fd, 1))
    {
        printf("server: Error on call 'listen': %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    struct pollfd pfd_array[1 /* listen */ + MAX_CLIENTS] =
    {
        {
            .fd = listen_sock_fd,
            .events = POLLIN
        }
    };
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; i++)
    {
        pfd_array[1 + i].fd = -1;
    }
    struct pollfd *listen_sock = pfd_array;

    int clients_count = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        int ret = poll(pfd_array, 1 + MAX_CLIENTS, -1 /* infinity */);
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            printf("Error on call 'poll': %s", strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            // обработка попытки подключения клиента
            if ((listen_sock->revents & POLLIN) != 0)
            {
                listen_sock->revents &= ~POLLIN;

                struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;
                socklen_t clilen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
                int sock_fd = accept(listen_sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, &clilen);
                if (sock_fd > 0)
                {
                    // ограничение числа подключений
                    if (clients_count == MAX_CLIENTS)
                    {
                        close(sock_fd);
                        printf("%d clients already connected, unexpected new connection have discarded\n", MAX_CLIENTS);
                    } else
                    {
                        clients_count++;
                        opt = 1;
                        setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void*)&opt, sizeof(opt));

                        for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; i++)
                        {
                            if (pfd_array[1 + i].fd == -1)
                            {
                                pfd_array[1 + i].fd = sock_fd;
                                pfd_array[1 + i].events = POLLIN;

                                printf("Client %d has been connected\nClients count = %d\n", i, clients_count);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; i++)
            {
                if (pfd_array[1 + i].fd != -1 && (pfd_array[1 + i].revents & POLLIN) != 0)
                {
                    pfd_array[1 + i].revents &= ~POLLIN;

                    uint8_t buf[64];
                    int ret = recv(pfd_array[1 + i].fd, buf, 64, 0);

                    if (ret < 0)
                    {
                        printf("Error on call 'recv': %s\n", strerror(errno));
                        return -1;
                    } else if (ret == 0)
                    {
                        close(pfd_array[1 + i].fd);
                        pfd_array[1 + i].fd = -1;
                        pfd_array[1 + i].events = 0;
                        clients_count--;
                        printf("Client %d has been disconnected\nClients count = %d\n\n", i, clients_count);
                    } else
                    {
                        printf("%d bytes received from client %d\n", ret, i);
                        printf("Message from client %d: %.*s\n", i, ret, (char *)buf);
                        if(-1 == send(pfd_array[1 + i].fd, (void *)"Response", 8, 0))
                        {
                            printf("Error on call 'send': %s\n", strerror(errno));
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: не то что «лучше», а скорее дело вкуса и привычки...

Comment: ну, не совсем. спорить не буду)